помогите разобраться к установкой библиотеки mysql-shim
столкнулся с такой проблемой, как необходимая миграция с php 5.6 на php 8.x
Переписывать весь старый код уже нет времени, хостер отключит поддержку php 5.6 в ближайшее время.
Нашел в интернете информацию, что можно сохранить работоспособность сайта и сохранить старый код, используя библиотеки-прослойки.
Я выбрал https://github.com/dotpointer/mysql-shim.
Вроде бы есть инструкция, но так, как я практически ноль в правильном синтаксисе, правильно указать путь к библиотеке в файле php.ini не смог, так же не уверен, что положил сам файл библиотеки в нужную директорию. Инструкция полностью на английском, через гугл переводчик полная еруда получается.
В инструкции указан пример пути: include_path = ".:/path/to/directory/where/mysql-shim.php/is/located:/usr/lib/php"
Вот дерево моих каталогов:

Не могу понять как правильно прописать include_path в php.ini и куда я должен положить саму библиотеку. В инструкции сказано: "Вы можете поместить файл в каталог, охватываемый глобальными путями включения, указанными в файле php.ini" Помогите с примером.

Найди лучше хостинг с такой древностью (или возьми ВПС). А потом уже пробуй играться.

Это какая-то помойка, а не библиотека. Скачиваете https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim/master/lib/mysql.php этот файл, подключаете в свои скрипты, всё работает

Кто-то ещё использует PHP 5.6? И как долго ты будешь легаси код затыкивать костылями? https://endoflife.date/php На месте хостера я бы и PHP 7 отключил =)
